# NASA spice tipbod spiceypy

Tags: python, astropy

Attempting to get the body fixed conditions of planets, RA, DEC, PM,  using the NASA example at. 
ftp://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/FORTRAN/spicelib/tipbod.html

TIPBOD is used to transform a position in J2000 inertial coordinates to a state in bodyfixed coordinates.
    TIPM = TIPBOD ('J2000', BODY, ET)

Then convert position, the first three elements of STATE, to bodyfixed coordinates. What is STATE?
    BDPOS = MXVG( TIPM, POSTN)

My code:

```
Targ = 399 (Earth)
et = spice.str2et(indate)
TIPM = spice.tipbod( "J2000", Targ, et )  
BDPOS = spice.mxvg(TIPM, POSTN, BDPOS )
```

but what is POSTN and what is BDPOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a bit more detail about the inputs to the spiceypy functions by searching for the relevant function [here](http://spiceypy.readthedocs.io/en/master/documentation.html).

In your particular case `TIPM` will be a 3x3 2D matrix that provides the transformation between an object in the inertial frame and a body fixed frame.  The required inputs to the `mxvg` function are given [here](http://spiceypy.readthedocs.io/en/master/documentation.html?highlight=mxvg#spiceypy.spiceypy.mxvg). In your case `POSTN` should be a list (or numpy array) of 3 values giving the x, y, and z positions of the body you're interested in. `BODPOS` will be the output of `mxvg`, which will be the matrix `TIPM` multiplied by the vector `POSTN`, so will be a vector containing three values: the transformed x, y, and z positions of the body.

I'm not entirely sure what you require, but an example might be:

```
from astropy.time import Time
from spiceypy import spiceypy as spice

# create a time
t = Time('2010-03-19 11:09:00', format='iso')

# put in spice format - this may require a leap seconds kernel to be
# downloaded, e.g. download https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/lsk/naif0012.tls
# and then load it with spice.furnsh('naif0012.tls')
et = spice.str2et(t.iso)

# get the transformation matrix - this may require a kernel to be
# downloaded, e.g. download https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/pck/pck00010.tpc
# and then load it with spice.furnsh('pck00010.tpc')
target = 399 # Earth
TIPM = spice.tipbod( "J2000", target, et )

# get the position that you want to convert
from astropy.coordinates import Angle, ICRS
ra = Angle('12:32:12.23', unit='hourangle')
dec= Angle('-01:23:52.21', unit='deg')

# make an ICRS object (you can also input a proper motion as a radial velocity or using 'pm_dec' and 'pm_ra_cosdec' keyword arguments)
sc = ICRS(ra=ra, dec=dec)

# get position in xyz
xyz = sc.cartesian.xyz.value

# perform conversion to body centred frame
newpos = spice.mxvg(TIPM, xyz, 3, 3)

# convert to latitude and longitude
scnew = SkyCoord(x=newpos[0], y=newpos[1], z=newpos[2], representation_type='cartesian')

# print out new RA and dec
print(scnew.spherical.lon, scnew.spherical.lat)
```

There are probably ways of doing this entirely within astropy, either with a predefined frame or by definition your own, and using the `transform_to()` method of the [`ICRS`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/v2.0.x/api/astropy.coordinates.ICRS.html#astropy.coordinates.ICRS) object. For example, you could convert from ICRS to [GCRS](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.GCRS.html#astropy.coordinates.GCRS).

Comment: Thanks, Matt,I'm trying to get the PoleRA, PoleDEC, and PolePM for Earth. My application is simple, an astronomical display using 24 steppers to position the planets and moons according to spice data.  After reading your response, isn't the TIPM matrix what I want?

Comment: @creeser - you may not need to use spicepy for what you want. From the sounds of it you may just be able to use the [get_body_barycentric()](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.get_body_barycentric.html) function in astropy (which uses [jplephem](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jplephem) and the same data as spice under the hood) to get the cartesian position of a planet with respect to the solar system barycentre, and then convert this into an RA & Dec as seen from Earth by plugging the returned position into an astropy SkyCoord object.

Comment: @creeser - I think you could use the TIPM matrix to do this as well though. You could again use get_body_barycentric() to get the position of a planet at a given time `xyz`, plug this in to `mxvg(TIPM, xyz, 3, 3)`, and again convert the output to an RA and Dec as seen from Earth.

Comment: Thanks Matt, looks like tipbod and reclat works.  Tell me if I wrong, but the numbers look ok.  #Saturn Tilt Negative rotation
    Targ = 699
    TIPM = spice.tipbod( "J2000", Targ, et )   
    #Rotation
    Radius, Long, lat = spice.reclat(TIPM[0])
    fy = r2d * Long
    if fy < 0.0:
        fy = fy + 360.0 #if degrees/radians are negative, add 360
    #print 'X Longitude  = ' +str(fy)

    #Tilt
    Radius, Long, lat = spice.reclat(TIPM[1])
    fy = r2d * Long
    if fy < 0.0:
        fy = fy + 360.0
    #print 'Y Longitude = ' +str(fy)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt, looks like tipbod and reclat works.  Tell me if I wrong, but the numbers look ok.

```
#Saturn Tilt Negative rotation
    Targ = 699
    TIPM = spice.tipbod( "J2000", Targ, et )   
    #Rotation
    Radius, Long, lat = spice.reclat(TIPM[0])
    fy = r2d * Long
    if fy < 0.0:
        fy = fy + 360.0 #if degrees/radians are negative, add 360
    #print 'X Longitude  = ' +str(fy)

    #Tilt
    Radius, Long, lat = spice.reclat(TIPM[1])
    fy = r2d * Long
    if fy < 0.0:
        fy = fy + 360.0
    #print 'Y Longitude = ' +str(fy)
```

Comment: I think I'm still a bit confused about what you're actually trying to do, so I'm not sure if I can help any further. I'm not sure the row entries in TIPM are just rectangular coordinates that you can plug into `reclat`, but if the numbers seem ok then maybe it's correct for your purpose!